# Как создать хранимую процедуру на основе запроса от программы?

Tags: sql, sql-server, хранимые-процедуры

Такое выдает профайлер когда моя программа посылает запрос, вот как мне создать хранимую процедуру на основе этого? Хранимые процедуры были утеряны((

```
declare @p3 int
    set @p3=NULL
    declare @p4 int
    set @p4=NULL
    declare @p5 int
    set @p5=NULL
    exec dbo.GetUserList 0,54,@p3 output,@p4 output,@p5 output
    select @p3, @p4, @p5
    go


Вот что IDA полказывает .rdata:004F6D8C aCallDboApGetac_0 db '{CALL dbo.GetUserList(?,?,?,?,?)}',0 .rdata:004F6D8C ; DATA XREF: AccountDB::GetUserMaxLevel(int,uchar &,int &,int &):loc_417619↑o
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ну этого никто не подскажет. Мы же не представляем что такое 0, 54 и что возвращается в параметрах p3, 4, 5. Это только вы примерно представляя что происходит у вас в системе можете попробовать догадаться что это такое. Или посмотрев исходники той программы, которая вызывает такую процедуру. Плюс к этому надо еще структуру БД знать

Comment: Как создавать процедуры в sql server или в чём вопрос? Как создавать описано в документации https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax

Comment: Вот что IDA полказывает .rdata:004F6D8C aCallDboApGetac_0 db '{CALL dbo.GetUserList(?,?,?,?,?)}',0 .rdata:004F6D8C ; DATA XREF: AccountDB::GetUserMaxLevel(int,uchar &,int &,int &):loc_417619↑o

Answer (score 2):

А я понял, в чем вопрос!

Насколько я понял - у Вас были перенесены (откуда то) данные в таблицах, а программные обьекты-такие, как функции и/или хранимые процедуры-забыли перенести (возможно, просто потому, что не знали об их существовании). Но это - мои предположения.

И теперь у Вас такая задача по своеобразному реверс-инжинирингу: есть обращения к хранимкам, но нет самих процедур.

Как я понимаю, в этом случае Ida бесполезен, и опираться при восстановлении можно только на названия процедур, типы их аргументов и уже хранящуюся в таблицах информацию.

Ну, то есть, если процедура называется GetUsers - то понятно, что процедура должна возвращать список пользователей. Дальше смотрим таблицу пользователей, и пытаемся придумать, какие ее столбцы было бы логично вернуть в ответ, чтобы они соответствовали списку выходных аргументов хранимой процедуры. И так далее...

Иногда, насколько я знаю, ещё логику, реализованную в хранимых, переносят в код программы. У этого подхода есть свои плюсы и минусы, нужно "смотреть по обстановке", делать ли так